# Unconfigure Exchange from accepting mail for multiple domains

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

For some time my company (A) hosted the email (Exchange 2010) for another company (B).

Company B has moved their email to another hosted solution.  That went smooth.  They are getting their email on the new system.  Their mailboxes are still on our server but mail isn't being delivered there so those mailboxes are just sitting there.  (until I do something with them)

However whenever I try to send an email from A.com to B.com it is being delivered to the mailbox hosted on my Exchange server and not the new server they're using.  I've removed B.com as an Accepted Domain and the associated E-mail Address Policies for B.com.  What am I missing?  Have I done something wrong?

How do I make it so I can send mail from A.com to B.com and it arrive in B.com's users' mailbox on their new setup?

Answer (score 3):

Add an email address for a.com to the mailboxes for the b.com users and remove the b.com addresses. Or just delete the mailboxes.

Comment: After removing B.com from the accepted domains list, it will reject incoming messages from outside the Exchange organization for B.com. However, if joeuser@B.com is still listed for an individual user mailbox, messages from within the Exchange organization addressed to joeuser@b.com will be delivered to that mailbox.

Comment: Progress, maybe.  I've permanently removed a mailbox from A.com's server.  This user exists on B.com's server.

When sending from A.com to B.com in Outlook it fails.
  550 5.1.1 RESOLVER.ADR.ExRecipNotFound

Sending from A.com to B.com in OWA succeeds.

Comment: You are the victim of Outlook's addressing cache. When you try to address a message, you will probably be given a type-ahead lookup. Click the X on that entry so it is deleted. Then address it again.

Comment: I've done that multiple times.  No dice.  nslookup is enlightening.  Though I don't know what to do about it.                      >nslookup -querytype=mx B.com
Server:  domaincontroller.A.com
Address:  192.168.xxx.xxx

Non-authoritative answer:
B.com     MX preference = 20, mail exchanger = the.right.server.1
B.com     MX preference = 10, mail exchanger = the.right.server.2

the.right.server.1        internet address = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
the.right.server.2        internet address = yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy

Comment: Starting Outlook like this: outlook /cleanautocompletecache worked.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please click the checkmark to the left of it to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Delete their mailboxes or delete their email addresses for the domain in question. If Exchange finds an object with the email address that you're sending to then Exchange is going to deliver the email to that object, regardless of your Accepted Domains and E-Mail Address Policies.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a policy for sending and receiving mails from both the domains, and then allow the users who can send the mail to outside.